# WCF Relay not receiving messages

Tags: wcf, azure, servicebus

I have several queues on the Azure service bus and are now setting up a WCF relay service (inhouse) for processing messages. I have written a console application that hosts this service and looks like this:

```
 var sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWcfService));

            try
            {
                sh.Open();

                foreach (var endpoint in sh.Description.Endpoints)
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Listening at: {0}", endpoint.Address));    

                Console.Write("Press ENTER to close");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ...
            }
            finally
            {
                sh.Close();
            }
```

MyWcfService is implementing an interface with the method

```
    [WebInvoke]
    [OperationContract]
    void ProcessMessage(IntegrationMessage message);
```

When executed, I get messages that tells me that the application is listening to three different sevicebus endpoints (which are the ones I have configured) so this seems to be correct.

When looking at the traffic through Fiddler I get only 4 rows:

```
200 HTTP    Tunnel to   xxx-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net:443
200 HTTPS   xxx-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net    /WRAPv0.9/  
200 HTTPS   xxx-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net    /WRAPv0.9/
200 HTTPS   xxx-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net    /WRAPv0.9/
```

which in my eyes seems correct as it returns 200 and I see in fiddler that it also return a wrap_access_token..?

The question is why are there not any additional requests for getting the actual messages? I was expecting additional calls to open the connection to the service bus, but none are made..

I know that there are messages on at least two of the three queue's.

Any help will be much appreciated, and I will provide more information if needed.